# Why is the time complexity so different in the below two solutions?

Tags: c++, boolean

I was trying to solve this Leetcode problem - https://leetcode.com/problems/partition-equal-subset-sum/. I came up with a memoized solution that never got accepted because apparently it took too much time. Below is that solution.

```
class Solution{
public:
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums){
        int totalSum = 0;
        for(auto value : nums)
            totalSum += value;
        if(totalSum%2 == 1)
            return false;
        return helper(nums, totalSum/2, 0);
    }
private:
    bool helper(vector<int> nums, int totalSum, int index){
        if(totalSum == 0)
            return true;
        if(totalSum < 0)
            return false;
        if(index == nums.size())
            return false;
        // Check in the cache
        pair<int, int> key = make_pair(totalSum, index);
        if(cache.count(key)){
            //cout << "Cache hit!\n";
            return cache[key];
        }
        // Include this
        bool include = helper(nums, totalSum-nums[index], index+1);
        // Exclude this
        bool exclude = helper(nums, totalSum, index+1);
        cache[key] = include || exclude;
        return cache[key];
    }
    map<pair<int, int>, bool> cache;
};
```

After trying for a while, I made a small change where instead of using "include" and "exclude" booleans, I just did the below and the time complexity improved so significantly that it dropped from ~1000ms to ~0ms. I am confused why did this happen? Why is using two booleans and then storing their result in a map so much slower than when not using them?

```
cache[key] = helper(nums, totalSum-nums[index], index+1) || helper(nums, totalSum, index+1);
```

Can anyone please enlighten me here? Pretty confused about it.

Comment: Boolean expressions are shortcut.  So `a || b` only evaluates `b` if `a` is false.   In your code, `include` being `true` would not stop the second call of `helper()` to evaluate `exclude`.   In the short-cut case, the second call of `helper()` only happens if the first returns `true`.   Since you are doing recursive calls, your approach will increase run times in a way depends on the recursion depth (i.e. the deeper the recursion, the slower it goes, compared with the shortcut solution).   Particularly if there are lots of cases where the first call returns true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version calls `helper` twice - once for `include` and once for `exclude`.  The second version, since it uses the logical-or operator, will not call the 2nd `helper` if the first `helper` is true.  In other words, if `include` is true, the `exclude` call is not made because it will not change the result of the expression.

Another performance hit is the `nums` parameter to `helper`.  You don't make any changes to it within the function, so you can pass it as `const vector<int> &nums` to avoid making an unnecessary copy of the entire content of the array.  `canPartition` can also take its parameter as a const reference since you do not modify it.

Comment: Oh! This makes perfect sense now. Thanks man for explaining this part.

Comment: If you expand on the relevance of passing an array by value vs reference, this would make an even better answer.

Comment: @John I didn't look at that, as it will have a pretty minor effect here, but I added a blurb explaining the difference.